# Prevent React hook from being called when state changes

Tags: reactjs

I noticed that when you use useState in a hook and then use setState to change the value that is being cached, the hook will be called again and re-render the component. While this may be desired most of the time, I have one case where I don't want to re-render when the state changes.  This case is when you have a navigation menu (tabs) at the top of the page and when you click on a tab, it shows content in a pane beneath it. I really only want to hide the content for the tab that is currently shown and then display the content for the tab that is selected. When content is hidden, this is essentially setting the css "display" style to "none". This is desirable to preserve the state of the content's pane and also avoid effects like retrieving data.

I can think of one solution to handle this but it does require splitting the components into isolated modules. I am curious though whether there is a way to change state but without having the side effect of a component being re-rendered.

Comment: Could you show some code? So that it would be easier to understand your problem.

Comment: If the component doesn't have to be redrawn to reflect the state change, you can use `useRef` instead. You can keep around any type of value in a ref, not just component refs. (e.g `const counter = useRef(0).current`). Although, I suspect that in your case the parent component does have to re-render. In that case, you can use `memo` on children to prevent them from re-rendering.

Comment: @giotskhada I believe you are correct about using memo. I read through the React docs, but when I finished reading up everything on Hooks, it seemed that all the older stuff (prior to Hooks) was obsolete and I was given the impression to avoid using it. But it appears that memo is still valid to be used.